# Range.SpecialCells with varying results

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

This is another weird one.

I have this code which takes data from one sheet using filters and is using the `Range.SpecialCells()` method to find the appropriate rows to copy and paste. However, if I used `Rows().SpecialCells()` or if I used the row property of the range returned by `SpecialCells` the count of rows is wrong. Here's what I mean:

```
With Worksheets("ret-" & sNumRet)
    .EnableAutoFilter = True
    .AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=sSection
    iLast = Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
    numRows = .Range("B2:B" & iLast).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
End With
```

This code yields around 8k rows which is a number that makes sense.

```
With Worksheets("ret-" & sNumRet)
    .EnableAutoFilter = True
    .AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=sSection
    iLast = Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
    numRows = .Rows("2:" & iLast).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
End With
```

Yields 4 as a result.

```
With Worksheets("ret-" & sNumRet)
    .EnableAutoFilter = True
    .AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=sSection
    iLast = Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
    numRows = .Range("B2:B" & iLast).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
End With
```

Also yields 4 as a result. Both of those are of course wrong. I have 45k rows of data and I can see that at least a few thousands are displayed using the filter. Is there some difference of meaning I am missing between those statements ? I would expect them to be almost equivalent in the context here.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't really have to do with `SpecialCells`, rather how Excel counts rows.  `Rows.Count` returns counts for each contiguous `Area` in the range being counted.  For example, in the Immediate window:

```
? range("a2:a3,a5:a7").cells.Count
```

returns 5

```
? range("2:3,5:7").rows.Count
```

returns 2

```
? range("2:3,5:7").areas(1).rows.Count
```

returns 2

```
? range("2:3,5:7").areas(2).rows.Count
```

returns 3

As you can see, if you don't specify an area the first one is returned.

To get an answer for all areas loop through them:

```
Sub CountRows()
Dim i As Long
Dim RowTotal As Long

With ActiveSheet.Range("2:3,5:7")
    For i = 1 To .Areas.Count
        RowTotal = RowTotal + .Areas(i).Rows.Count
    Next i
End With
Debug.Print RowTotal
End Sub
```